# PHP How to append to an output by concatenation?

Tags: php, append, concatenation

I am a beginner PHP writer so please bear with me.

I have a simple situation that is sort of like this:

Line 1 $output .= 'ABC'

Line 2 $output .= 'DEFGHIJKLMN'

Line 3 echo $output;

Now, the code within my 'DEFGHIJKLMN' string has become super long. I am thinking about moving the content of 'DEFGHIJKLMN' to an external file for ease of editing, and somehow make the new file append to the end of $output.

So now I need to edit Line 2 to target the external file.

Please let me know how to do this, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, to append the contents of a file, use

```
$output .= file_get_contents("path_to_my_file.txt");
```

If you just want to break it across multiple source lines, do

```
$output .= "Long Line 123".
           "Continues here";
```

Answer (score 0):

You must have an `$output` variable in your code somewhere in a file you included. You can overwrite the variable like this:

```
$output = 'ABC';
```

instead of

```
$output .= 'ABC';
```

so your code could look like:

```
$output = 'ABC';
$output .= 'DEFGHIJKLMN';
echo $output;
```

or just change your variable name. That's what I would do. I also wouldn't see a need to concatenate this String.